# Submit <s:radio> tag selection with different attribute from the one being displayed

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

For the sake of simplicity, I will define the scenario as: class `Person` defines an object with an `id` (`int`) and a `name` (`String`) attribute. I created a `List<Person> persons`, which are loaded into the JSP page by its respective Action class method (`getPersons()`), to populate an `<s:radio>` tag. So far, so good, the JSP populates the `<s:radio>` accordingly. I can select and submit an option to the action class (defined in the JSP's `<form>` element). My problem is that I can only submit the *name* of the selected Person in the `<s:radio>`, when what I really want is to submit the Person's `id`. How can I do it?

**Practical example:** I have 2 Persons on the `<s:radio>` list, John (with ID=1), and Peter (with ID=2). I want to display their names on the `<s:radio>` element, but if I choose Peter, I want to submit `2` to the action class, instead of its name.

Code below:

**JSP**

```jsp
<form action="submitData" class="ink-form all-100 small-100 tiny-100" method="post">
    <s:radio label="persons" name="personId" list="persons.{name}" />
</form>
```

**Action class (submitData action)**

```java
public class SubmitData extends ActionSupport
{
    private String personId;

    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Person ID: "+personId);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setPersonId(String PersonId)
    {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OGNL this `persons.{name}` is called projection and you don't really need it in `<s:radio>` tag. Use `listKey` and `listValue` attributes to define which property of the objects inside list will be shown and which submitted.

```jsp
<s:radio label="persons" name="personId" list="persons" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

One more thing. Person `id` is an `int` and you are trying to submit it to `personId` which is a String. Of course it will work but consider changing `personId` to `int`. In that way, later when you want to retrieve `Person` object from the database you don't need to convert String back to `int`.

Comment: I've tried previously to use both `listKey` and `listValue` with no success (and thanks for pointing out the `personId` wrong type, btw!). Just one more doubt: I'm now having trouble presetting the `<s:radio>` value (with the `value` attribute). I used to call a `getDefaultPersonName()` method in the action class (something like `value="defaultPersonName"`), and it worked, but after start using these new 2 attributes it's gone. Do you know how can I fix it? (and if you find it more approppriate, I can ask a new question)

Comment: @jaff: Now you are submitting `id` instead of `name` so `value` should be an `id` also.